# Real valued function as difference of two non-negative functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Let $f:S \to \mathbb R$ be a function. Show that $f=g-h$, for some $g,h:S \to [0,\infty)$.**

Clearly, $f(S) \subseteq \mathbb R \Rightarrow f(S) \subseteq (-\infty,0]\cup [0,\infty)$.

Let $S_{1}=(x \in S:f(x)\leq 0)$, and $S_{2}=(x \in S:f(x)\gneq 0)$.

Define $h =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  -f  & \mbox{ } x \in S_{1} \\
  0 & \mbox{ } x \in S_{2}
 \end{array}
\right. $ and $g =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{ } x \in S_{1} \\
  f & \mbox{ } x \in S_{2}
 \end{array}
\right. $

Then we have (*):

$$
(g-h)(S)=(g-h)(S_{1} \cup S_{2})=(g-h)(S_{1}) \cup (g-h)(S_{2})=(-h)(S_{1}) \cup g(S_{2})=f(S_{1}) \cup f(S_{2})=f(S).
$$

Hence, $f=g-h$.

I have doubts over assigning $0$ to $g$ and $h$ and (*) seems messed up.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should make one of your inequalities strict when defining $S_1$ and $S_2$.so that they are disjoint.

Comment: Showing that $g-h$ and $f$ have the same image doesn't imply that they are the same function, you should show that $(g-h)(x)=f(x), \, \forall x \in S$. The first part is correct, basically it's the definition of positive and negative part of a function.

Comment: @Paul: $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are disjoint as the inequality of $S_{2}$ is strict.

Comment: My bad, didn't see that.

Comment: @chak: I think $g$ and $h$ are defined in such a way that they take every value that $f$ takes at various points of the domain.

Comment: @JackT Yes i know, i'm just saying that in the (*) part i think it would be more correct to show that $\forall x \in S \rightarrow (g-h)(x)=f(x)$ instead of show that $(g-h)(S)=f(S)$ because for me $f(S)=Im(f)$ and so that does not imply $f=g-h$.

Comment: @chak: Okay, now I get your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f(x)$ is defined $\forall x \in S$ and $S_{1}=(x \in S:f(x) \leq 0)$ and $S_{1}=(x \in S:f(x)> 0)$.  We have $S = S_1 \cup S_2$. For $x \in S$, either $x \in S_1$ or $x \in S_2$. If $x \in S_1$ then $g(x) - h(x) = 0 - (- f(x)) = f(x)$. If $x \in S_2$ then $g(x) - h(x) = f(x) - 0 = f(x)$. I.e. in either case $g-h = f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot...